# How can I print the contents of a table to the console?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

My customer sends me complicated (and inconsistent) data. I am using C# and calling stored procedures in the database using the Entity Framework 6 to insert that data into the database. (The Entity Framework portion is only really handling data retrieval and ensuring a correct schema; inserts are done completely through stored procedures using table-valued parameter procedures.)

I use a series of `Select DISTINCT` statements to pull the unique entities out of the data and into temporary tables, then use those temporary tables to update the live database after verifying the data. (Credit to @srutzky for the idea.)

I want to be able to print the contents of those temporary tables during the procedure so I can inspect it and/or write it to a log. The data they send is messy, and I want to make sure that my `SELECT DISTINCT` queries are working right. (Spoilers: they are, but the customer's data has more holes in it than decaying Swiss cheese.)

The data can be inconsistent as well, so sometimes the same entity will have different types values on a field that it shouldn't, which will cause the `DISTINCT` query to select the same entity multiple times from the data and violate `UNIQUE` constraints in the table. I'm specifically trying to locate these "bad lines" of data both for logging purposes and to inform the customer that the data was wrong.

This all has to be automated in C#. The program, when finished, will run on a remote server that I will not have write access to, so I also need the entire process to be "hands-off" (no sqlcmd, no SSDT, etc. Just T-SQL.)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using sqlcmd?

Comment: Nope. I haven't used that tool before. The process needs to be completely hands-off, so I'd prefer something that I can use straight from T-SQL code. I'll look up sqlcmd to see if it will do what I need it to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "in-process"? Are you using SSMS? Why won't a simple `SELECT` work?

Comment: How do you get this data into SQL?   Not clear what your situation is.

Comment: What tool are you using that you want to print this in-process data from?

Comment: Lots of questions. I guess my question really was unclear, wasn't it? It has been once again updated. All of your questions should now be answered sufficently enough for you to answer mine! :)

Comment: If this is going to be hands off, what console did you want to print to?  Hands off implies that there is no development environment in play so there wouldn't be a console.  Do you mean that you would like to output to a txt or csv file?

Comment: Is the end-result process supposed to be interactive where you will review the data in the temp table at each step and decide to proceed or cancel? Or will it be a background process that you just want logged in case of errors? In either case, why not have the app code SELECT the data from the temp table, and then either A) display it and wait for your response before moving onto the next step, or B) log it to a file and just proceed with fingers crossed?

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin The program will run without supervision most of the time, but a console window will still appear. It may as well print something! And if I do have to run it on my local machine to debug it, I won't have to change anything to see the information I'd (likely) need to fix it. I'd also like it to output to a TXT or CSV file, but I'm not sure whether I should do that through C# (since EF traps output from the DB anyway) or T-SQL (since it can easily write files). I'm leaning towards C# for consistency (the rest of the program writes to a log using the Diagnostics classes).

Comment: @srutzky The end-result should be the table printing to the console and a log file. There is nothing interactive, but I will be stepping through the procedure during development. I essentially want to see what's going on in there while I'm stepping through it.

Comment: On a side note, holes in swiss cheese (or any other cheese for that matter) are _not_ a sign of decay.

Comment: @mustaccio I knew that. I in my head I was thinking that decaying cheese would have holes that were supposed to be there, holes that weren't supposed to be there, and mold everywhere. Probably the second worst analogy I've ever made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this all in the C# app code. Exporting data from T-SQL is not handled natively and requires SQLCLR, which is fine when needed, but it is not necessary here since you are already working within app code that can handle it quite cleanly.

You should have the app code do a `SELECT` (or grab the contents via EF if you say it can do that easily) and log it to a file after each step.

You should also have a command-line option/flag, or a check-box in the UI before clicking "Start", for "Debug mode" that will additionally display what is being written to disk along with an option to "Continue" or "Cancel".

Comment: I usually have a debug option in final versions of any of my programs.

C# definitely does seem like the better option in my case, but I'm pretty unsure of myself sometimes (especially when I'm doing something I've never done before; all of the database work I've done up until now has been school projects), I'm just not sure how to get the info out of the temporary tables. I'm thinking that I have my error logging tables as out parameters and, in the case of an exception, go through them and print/log the contents.

Comment: @sonicbhoc Tables cannot be `OUTPUT` parameters. But again, you can SELECT from them. You can pass a parameter into the stored procs to use in `IF` blocks wrapped around the SELECT statements so that they only do the SELECT in "debug" mode. Of course, if you are doing this within the proc itself, then you don't really have an opportunity to "cancel" the operation since the "review" will be after the action has occurred.

Comment: I'm fine with that. I found out yesterday that Visual Studio will let me step through database code in the debugger the same way I can step through C# code. And even if I couldn't cancel it, having it in the log is almost always good enough for most of the kinds of programs I'm writing.